# How to navigate inside a UINavigationController which is inside a UITabBarController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a project that is a tab-bar controller.  Each tab usually has a UINavigationController.  The problem I have is this:  I need a new tab with alot of navigation (roughly 30 navigation items grouped into 4-8 groups.  Problem:  My navigation bar is already full (can't use the navigation controller (or bar).  What I need is navigation below the navigation bar (which has a global search bar and other global icons filling it).  How can I implement this best?

What I have now:  I have created a UIScrollView just under the navigation bar to serve as my "hand-rolled" navigation bar.  It's a scrollView because I don't know (going forward) how many "groupings" of navigation items I will have (currently only 4).  Each of these groups is represented by a UIButton, some of which should immediately present a view, and others which present a popover with further navigation items, which when selected will present a view.

Problem:  I want a "content view" under my navigation view mentioned above, where I can present content based on the user's navigation choices.  I have to support iOS 5.0, so I can't use the storyboard container view (unfortunately).  I will have 3 types (maybe more later) of content views I will present, that I would like to create as individual view controllers and then push the appropriate one as it's selected in my navigation mentioned.  Is there a 3rd party navigation controller I can use?  Do I have to "roll my own"?  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Here is a "slapped-together" picture of what I need to achieve:
[image]

Comment: Can you add a picture of what you want?

Comment: Ok.  I slapped one together and posted in my question.  The tab bar and navigation bar are existing, and I can't use that nav bar at top for navigation on this tab.  Depending on the navigation selection in My hand rolled UIScrollBar, I will present some content in the content view.  Maybe in a grid style layout, maybe in a cover-flow, maybe a web view.  I will have different "templates" as view controllers to present their own complex views hierarchies.

Comment: Your problem is not stated clearly. We know too little about your various controllers to judge if you need to "roll your own". If subclassing `UIViewController`s is "roll your own" then, yes, you will have to do that.

Comment: Thanks for your sarcasm, but I'm talking about needing a UINavigationController, but I can't use that because there already is one and I can't use it, so instead of nesting another UINavigationController and having 2 navigation bars, I need something that looks better than that, but achieves the same thing...

Comment: Go to apple's appstore and look at the "Featured" tab.  That's the situation I have, except that I have a navigation bar at the very top, which I can't use. So it looks like they have a segmented control at the top (which could be my "hand-rolled" navigation bar, but it has to go under the other one, and I need a good method for pushing and popping complex view controllers into the remaining "content-area".

Comment: You can still use custom container controllers in iOS 5, you just have to do them in code rather than using the container views in IB. Having 30 navigation items sounds like an awfully complex hierarchy. Why not just have a table view in the above pictured controller, and push to your content controller depending on the selection?

Comment: I agree.  The simple answer -- We have designers that know better than apple.  Don't get me started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make what you're calling the content view a subview of your main view, and use it as the view to which you will add a childViewController's view. If you haven't already read up on custom container controllers, you should do so, but the basic way of using them is like this.

The controller's whose view you show in your question would be the custom container controller. You could load up an initial controller in the viewDidLoad method, then switch the controller in your subview (I'm calling it self.containerView) in response to the user choosing something from your scroll bar:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    UIViewController *initial = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"InitialVC"];
    [self addChildViewController:initial];
    [initial.view.frame = self.containerView.bounds];
    [self.containerView addSubview:initial.view];
    self.currentController = initial;
}

-(void)switchToNewViewController:(UIViewController *) cont {
    [self addChildViewController:cont];
    cont.view.frame = self.containerView.bounds;
    [self moveToNewController:cont ];
}

-(void)moveToNewController:(UIViewController *) newController {
    [self.currentController willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
    [self transitionFromViewController:self.currentController toViewController:newController duration:.6 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft animations:^{}
         completion:^(BOOL finished) {
             [self.currentController removeFromParentViewController];
             [newController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
             self.currentController = newController;
         }];
}
```

This should give you the basic idea. I took this from one of my test projects, so it will probably need a little tweaking.

Comment: I was hoping not to have to do this because of the vast pitfalls and implications, but it looks like this is my only option.

Comment: @HackyStack, I haven't really noticed that many pitfalls. The problem I see sometimes has to do with sizing (and rotation) of the child views. Usually, I use layout constraints now, rather than setting the frame directly, but both approaches can work.